# How can I exclude a directory from an .htaccess 301 rewrite on a domain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, svn

I've spent the last hour trying to read, learn and figure this out myself but didn't get very far so I figured I would see if any of you might know the answer to this.

I basically have a 301 redirect on one of my domains (`firstdomain.com`) that points all requests to my other domain (`seconddomain.com`).

Easy enough, but now I have added a SVN repository onto `firstdomain.com/svn`. But because all requests sent to `firstdomain.com` are being redirected I need to find a way to exclude the 301 redirect if the URL looks for the `/svn/` subfolder.

How can I make this happen?

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but something to the effect of the following (in `firstdomain.com`'s .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/svn.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]

Redirect 301 / http://www.seconddomain.com/
```

In theory (something that usually takes a lot of tinkering with htacess) this should stop rewrite rules for any svn requests, but those that dont match the svn condition will be redirected 301.

Comment: Thank you! I thought this was working but now that my SVN client is accessing the domain at `firstdomain.com/svn` I'm getting an error saying that this domain has moved to `seconddomain.com/svn` so it seems the 301 is still overriding the exclusion…